# Matching a variable with lists and printing list value

Tags: python

I need some help on my code below,I have the sample input and expected output,currenlty its not printing anything..please provide your inputs,

Basically my code is parsing the values in num_ids.txt and checking if each value is greater than the base_num value provided and also if the value is not in "num_ignore" list and then(after first 2 conditions are met) it tries to match numrefs list and prints the matched value in numrefs...

```
EXPECTEDOUTPUT:-
nums/39/205739/2

import os
import subprocess
def p4 (base_num):
    numrefs = ['nums/89/202089/4', 'nums/39/205739/2', 'nums/94/203455/6']
    num_ignore = [150362, 147117]
    '''
        num_ids.txt
        202089
        205739
        147117
        203455
    '''
    with open('./num_ids.txt', 'rb') as f:
        # Iterate over the file itself
        for line in f:
            num = int(line)
            if num > base_num and num not in num_ignore and line in numrefs:
                print numrefs
def main():
    base_num=203456
    p4(base_num)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Seems like you are using a Python version that lacks support for the "with" construct. Try `from __future__ import with_statement`

Comment: @Tavlvalin - i fixed the version issue...currently my code doesnt print anything...can you provide inputs on why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the `numrefs` list into a dict called `numrefs_index` using a comprehension.  That way you can use the `in` operator and access the references more quickly.

```
def p4(base_num):
    numrefs = ['nums/89/202089/4', 'nums/39/205739/2', 'nums/94/203455/6']
    num_ignore = [150362, 147117]
    numrefs_index = dict((int(x.split('/')[2]), x) for x in numrefs)
    for line in file("num_ids.txt"):
        num = int(line)
        if num > base_num and num not in num_ignore and num in numrefs_index:
            print numrefs_index[num]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p4(203456)

# prints:
# nums/39/205739/2
```

The `numrefs_index` line builds this dict:

```
{202089: 'nums/89/202089/4',
 203455: 'nums/94/203455/6',
 205739: 'nums/39/205739/2'}
```

Comment: thanks for correcting my expected output..I updated the question...I cant put in a dict for now ..at the max I can store them as integers..do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I added one way to do it using a list.  If your lists of refs and ids are very large, a faster way would be to transform the list into a dict...

Comment: I edited with a better way...  The `numrefs_index` line transforms the refs list into a dict for faster access

Comment: Thanks a lot slace diamond..this is much better implementation